# in jquery i use this code but this show nothing to me what is ther error in this code

Tags: javascript

in jQuery I use this code but this show nothing to me what is there error in this code

```
 // $.ajax({
    //     URL:"https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random",
    //     method:"GET",
    //     success:function(data){
    //         var myurl=data.message;
           
    //     $("#dog-image").attr("src",myurl);
    //     }
    // });
```

Comment: I assume in the actual code it's not commented out?

Comment: We also need to see the html code

Comment: Is the success callback called? Put some breakpoint or console.log in it. Perhaps there is some error and it never gets called.

Comment: and write the url in smallcase, it is a key. not 'URL' but 'url'

Answer (score 1):

The property, `URL`, should be lowercase, `url`, [per the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/Jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-url-settings).

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random",
  method: "GET",
  success: function(data) {
    var myurl = data.message;

    $("#dog-image").attr("src", myurl);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img id="dog-image" />
```